# How to UITest UIProgressView?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing, uiprogressview

**Situation:**

I want to UI-test my progress view and see if it's progress has increased.

**What I've tried:**

By using a breakpoint in my UI-test and using the `po print(app.debugDescription`), I can successfully see and access the `UIProgressView` element.

It's called: 
`Other, 0x6080003869a0, traits: 8589935104, {{16.0, 285.5}, {343.0, 32.0}}, identifier: 'progressView', label: 'Progress', value: 5%`

I access it with `let progressView = secondTableViewCell.otherElements["progressView"]`, which works, as `.exists` returns true.

Now, to check progress, the description above hints at the 'value' property, that is currently at 5%. However, when I try `progressView.value as! String` or Double or whichever, I cannot seem to get the property as it isn't NSCoder-compliant.

**Question:**

Is it possible to UI-test a UIProgressView and use it's progress value?

**My final custom solution:**

Using the value property (when casting to String) somehow does work now. As I wanted to check if progress increased over time, I strip the String to get the numeric progress in it to compare. Here is my solution I use now:

```
// Check if progress view increases over time
let progressView = secondTableViewCell.otherElements["progressView"]
XCTAssert(progressView.exists)

let progressViewValueString = progressView.value as! String
// Extract numeric value from '5%' string
let progressViewValue = progressViewValueString.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined()

// Let progress increase
sleep(3)

let newProgressViewValueString = progressView.value as! String
let newProgressViewValue = newProgressViewValueString.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined()
XCTAssert(newProgressViewValue > progressViewValue)
```

Comment: `let progressView = app.otherElements["progress"]` didn't work for me. 
But this did:

        let x = app.progressIndicators["progress"]

        XCTAssertTrue(x.exists)
        XCTAssertEqual(x.value as! String, "55%")

Comment: Weird, I'm getting the opposite with iOS 11 simulator and XCode 9. Exists works for the `otherElements` property, but not for the `progressIndicators` property :/. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**XCUIElement** conforms to **XCUIElementAttributes** which gives you access to a `value` property of type `Any?`

The actual type of `value` at runtime depends on which kind of UI element you are querying. In case of a UIProgressView it is of type `__NSCFString`, which is a concrete subclass of `NSString`. Which means you can safely cast it to `String`:

This works (provided that you set your progress view's accessibility identifier to "progressView"):

```
func testProgressView() {
   let app = XCUIApplication()
   app.launch()

   let progressView = app.progressIndicators["progressView"]
   // alternative (if the above query does not work):
   // let progressView = app.otherElements["progressView"]
   let currentValue = progressView.value as? String
   XCTAssertEqual(currentValue, "5 %")
}
```

Weirdly in some cases the `progressIndicator` query does not work. In that case you can try a `otherElements` query (see comment in above code)

Comment: I don't know why, but somehow casting to String didn't work before and now it does. However, `progressIndicators` doesn't work for me to get a `UIProgressView` element. `otherElements` does for me. If you change it to that, I'll accept the answer

Comment: That's weird. In my case (Xcode9, iPhone8 Simulator) it's the other way around: `otherElements` does not work, `progressIndicators` does work. I'll add both queries to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Weird indeed, as many UITesting things are at the moment :(.